# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array<Swift.String>' (0x61000028bb50) to 'Swift.String' (0x10cbd0ae0)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a program that does an initial search of users then populates a table.  There are two buttons within the table to accept the users request and another to deny, these buttons call an insert function that inputs the results in the database.  The array results are being passed to the function but I'm getting an error of '**Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array' (0x61000028bb50) to 'Swift.String' (0x10cbd0ae0)'** on the following line of code:

```
    self.insertShot("No", (gname as? String as AnyObject))
```

The gname variable is declared as follows:
        var gname = String

Here is the code that is getting the array data:

```
    for i in 0 ..< self.guest.count {

    let ava = self.guest[i]["ava"] as? String

    let gname = self.guest[i]["username"] as? String
    let city = self.guest[i]["city"] as? String
    let state = self.guest[i]["state"] as? String
    let url = NSURL(string: ava!)! 
    self.avas.append(image)
    self.gname.append((gname as AnyObject) as! String)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

InsertShot function

```
public func insertShot(_ rating : String,_ gname : AnyObject) {
    // shortcuts to data to be passed to php file

    let reviewer = user?["username"] as! String
    print("print 3", gname)        

    // url path to php file
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx.php")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // param to be passed to php file
    let param = [
        "user" : reviewer,
        "revieweduser" : gname,
        "rating" : rating
    ] as [String : Any]

    // body
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // ... body
    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParams(param as? [String : String], boundary: boundary)


    // launch session
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        // get main queu to communicate back to user
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {


            if error == nil {

                do {

                    // json containes $returnArray from php
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    // declare new var to store json inf
                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")
                        return
                    }

                    // get message from $returnArray["message"]
                    let message = parseJSON["users"]
                    //print(message)

                    // if there is some message - post is made
                    if message != nil {

                        // reset UI
                        // self.msgTxt.text = ""

                        // switch to another scene
                        //self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
                        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)


                    }

                } catch {

                    // get main queue to communicate back to user
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let message = "\(error)"
                        appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                    })
                    return

                }

            } else {

                // get main queue to communicate back to user
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    let message = error!.localizedDescription
                    appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                })
                return

            }


        })

        }.resume()
    return

}
```

The following functions are used when the Yes or No buttons are selected and they call the InsertShots function:

```
@IBAction func noBtn_clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("print 6", gname)
    self.insertShot("No", (gname as? String as AnyObject))
    //doSearch("")

}
@IBAction func yesBtn_clicked(_ sender: UIButton, users: AnyObject) {

    self.insertShot("Yes", (gname as? String as AnyObject))

}
```

Comment: `as? Any as! String as AnyObject` ... what.

Comment: I had it as String but Xcode gave autocorrect error messages that resulted in that.

Comment: Please add the definition for `insertShot`

Comment: @Alexander this is worse IMO: `(NSString(format: "%@", self.guest[i]["age"] as! CVarArg) as String)`

Comment: That's pretty disturbing code. The error message says *An **array** is passed where a **string** is expected*.

Comment: @techgirl08 It looks like you're having a local variable naming issue. `self.gname` is an array as evidenced by `self.gname.append`, but you also have local variables named `gname` that are strings. In Swift, you don't need to use `self.` to access variables. I would recommend changing the name of the array to `gnames` so that you can use `gname` as a local variable.

Comment: Thanks.  I've edited the code to show the InsertShot function above.

Comment: 5 down votes and no one bothered to explain how the question could be improved. I've seen much worse questions get way fewer down votes. The votes surely weren't because the code in question is bad, right?

Comment: Thanks Allen. I thought the 5 points was a big shocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you may be inadvertently passing the array `self.gname` instead of a simple `String`. From the context I have, I can't tell if you're trying to pass in an array or a string. Your code is making much too much use of the "no type" types, such as `Any` and `AnyObject`. You are explicitly disabling the safety and the helpfulness of the Swift type system.

I'd recommend changing your function declaration to indicate exactly what you need. Such as:

```
public func insertShot(_ rating: String, _ gname: String)
```

then within the body, you can change your dictionary declaration to

```
let param = [
    "user" : reviewer,
    "revieweduser" : gname,
    "rating" : rating
]
```

Then drop the cast:

```
request.httpBody = createBodyWithParams(param, boundary: boundary)
```

You are passing in `self.gname` which is an `Array` of `String`s. You need to pass in a `String`.

Change you could to this:
    if let gnameString = self.gname.first {
        self.insertShot("Yes", gnameString)
    }

Note: Your code is creating an array, you presumably need to figure out **which** value in the array you want to pass in.

Comment: Thanks Allen, my intention is to pass the string.

Comment: @techgirl08 Can you update your question to make it clear where exactly `self.insertShot("No", (gname as? String as AnyObject))` is in relation to other elements?

Comment: I've updated to show the two actions that call insertShots.

Comment: @techgirl08 I've updated my answer with some more advice.

Comment: Thanks Allen, I'm new to Swift so I'm learning as I go.  It is now passing a string but the same String for each row.  The labels for the rows are working fine just the value passed keeps repeating.

Comment: Unfortunately, without more information I can't advise how to index into that array. The solution I provided just gets the first value. You will need to figure out how to convert the user's interaction into an index into that array. If you provide the context for how the the `@IBActions` are configured, and what user interactions are involved we might be able to further help. It may also be the case that you should look around for other SO answers that could help you figure it out.

Comment: @techgirl08 if you found my work helpful, please at least up vote my answer. If you need more information to bring your question to a conclusion, please provide more guidance by editing your question to further pinpoint your issue.

Comment: I'll definitely update.  Still trying to work through the feedback you provided and see what else I need to provide.